# Zero Energy State of a Mechanical System?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, potential, kinetic-theory

Would a mechanical system in a particular frame (when I say mechanical I mean pulleys, elastic strings, etc.) that has no potential energy (loaded springs, pulled back elastic, hanging weights, etc.) or kinetic energy be at zero energy state? I am aware of zero energy state in the quantum context, but that is not what I am referring to here. I am asking this because I am in the process of building a projectile launcher for a school project and it must be at "zero energy state prior to launching the projectile," (excluding the potential energy of a 5 lb weight that will power the entire launcher.)

Comment: Uh...how are you defining "zero energy state" classically if not by having no potential or kinetic energy?

Comment: Well, no potential or kinetic energy in your local reference frame. There seems, perhaps, to be a real question in this, but it isn't coming out very well.

Comment: A comet in a parabolic orbit about the sun has zero mechanical energy. That's a basic sophomore mechanics drill problem.

Comment: My apologies for any lack of clarity. ACuriousMind, my question boils down to "What is zero energy state?" so I don't understand why I would need to define it. Jon Custer, the real question is, would a local frame without potential or kinetic energy be considered zero energy state?

Answer (score 3):

In classical mechanics, potential energy is only defined up to an arbitrary constant, and therefore total energy is only defined up to that arbitrary constant: in addition, the kinetic energy is reference-frame-dependent, and in the case of, say, $1/r^2$ force laws, it may not have a well-defined minimum.

For these reasons, "zero energy state" has no well-defined meaning, and saying that the system is "at a global minimum" of its potential energy (perhaps also saying that it is "stationary" or "in equilibrium" to clarify that it is stuck there) is more clear and well-defined.